# how do i fire an event when document readyState is complete

Tags: javascript

I want to fire and event when the DOM has completely loaded. I checked out `document.readyState` but it's not an event. I want to fire it when the `readyState` is complete. How do I do that?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

For anyone already using the jQuery library the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function can be used to handle this.

Otherwise the solution from @Neal will achieve the same functionality without needing to add an additional dependency.

Comment: Why suggest adding jquery to something where it may not even be needed?

Comment: Consider added an alternative suggestion to jquery as this is an answer that has been seen thousands of times in the past 5 years.

Comment: At the time of writing jQuery was in wide spread use and for may cases a suitable solution. I have added your solution @Neal as an alternative to avoid the additional dependency.

Answer (score 22):

Some easy googling point me to this code:

```
// alternative to DOMContentLoaded
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        initApplication();
    }
}
```

And to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/document.readystate)

Comment: It does not fires on Opera Developer at least, only `window.onload` do.

Comment: Still works as of 2022. Opera & Opera Android notes: `Opera Presto fires 'complete' late after the 'load' event (in an incorrect order as per HTML5 standard specification).` (from link in post above)

Comment: The comment 'alternative to DOMContentLoaded' within the post is incorrect. DOMContentLoaded is fired once when the DOM parser completes, while the readyState event fires 'interactive' when it finishes parsing and 'complete' when all its subresources have finished loading. This happens way after DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the [`window.load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload).

This will only fire when all external resources (including images) have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from another post, however, you could do it like this:

```js
var alreadyrunflag = 0; //flag to indicate whether target function has already been run

if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    alreadyrunflag = 1;
    // perform what you need to
  }, false);
} else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
  var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag");
  contentloadtag.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      alreadyrunflag = 1;
      // perform what you need to
    }
  }
}
//fallback
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!alreadyrunflag) {
      // perform what you need to
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

This checks that the DOM is fully loaded, however, if it isn't, it falls back to `onload`. You can obviously manipulate this though.

Also, if JQuery is an option, you can achieve the same effect by using just one simple function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
function startupApplication(anyFunction) {
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.onreadystatechange = () =>  
        document.readyState === "complete" ? anyFunction() : undefined;
    };
}

startupApplication(() => {
    // Put your code here ...
});
```

See my FiddleJS with comments and logs for education purposes: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/otenmoten/n1Luw768)