# document.readyState on DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, dom-events

In browsers that support the event `DOMContentLoaded` and the property `document.readyState`:

> When `DOMContentLoaded` fires, can I assume that the value of `document.readyState` will always be either `"complete"` or `"interactive"`/[`"loaded"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348029/values-for-document-readystate-in-android-2-3-browser)?
>
> (Or could it be that `document.readyState` sometimes still has the value `"loading"`?)

In your answer please provide a reference to an authoritative source.

You may wonder: Why not just listen to `readystatechange`? It is because the Android 2.3.5 standard browser is a target platform, and it does not implement the `readystatechange` event.

Comment: Why not just listen to `DOMContentLoaded`? ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android 2.3 supports the readystatechange event, but just uses loaded instead of interactive/complete. I'll investigate and get back.

Comment: UPDATE - Indeed you're correct. I've made a small test here: http://test.it-kollektivet.dk/white-space/android2.3.html But the only value I get from document.readyState is **loading** and **loaded**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of the `readyState` property is always `"interactive"` when `DOMContentLoaded` has fired. This is evidenced by the fact that the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState) claims:

```
// alternative to DOMContentLoaded event
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    initApplication();
  }
}
```

is interchangeable with a `DOMContentLoaded` handler. You can also have a look at the spec [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#event-readystatechange), which reiterates this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not right on Android 2.3.5. I just did a test, and the result is completely unexpected to me: When `DOMContentLoaded` fires, then the value of `document.readyState` is `"loaded"` (i.e. neither `"complete"`, nor `"interactive"`, nor `"loading"`).

Comment: @feklee That must be because there are no sub resources, in which case DOMContentLoaded and the load event fire simultaneously. Have a closer look at the spec I linked.

Comment: @feklee Once the load event fires it should be "complete", as in other browsers, not "loading". The sequence of values is "loading" -> "interactive" -> "complete". Guess Android isn't following the spec on this one, but to have "loading" after everything is loaded is just ridiculous. Are you sure there isn't a mistake in your test case?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Correct is: *Note that the value is "loaded", not "complete". Furthermore, once the "load" event fires, the value is "complete" as in other browsers.*

Comment: @feklee I was curious; this answer was not completely accurate as far as your problem was concerned. Why did you accept it? More importantly, how did you resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Well, you pointed me to MDN saying that the above code is an ["alternative to DOMContentLoaded"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState#Examples), and MDN is an authoritative source IMHO. As for the issue with Android 2.3: In my code, I simply treat `"interactive"` and `"loaded"` as identical. I've seen other code on the net doing the same (I forgot where it was, but it was in some popular project that again could be considered authoritative).

Comment: "interactive" can be setted to early in IE8/IE9

Comment: I appreciate that this is a very old answer, but there's a subtle difference that really caught me out.  `readyState` is set to `interactive` *before* scripts with the `defer` attribute are evaluated, while `DOMContentLoaded` is fired *after*.

Comment: @MTCoster i am automating browser with scripts, and this comment was really helpful to figure out difference between readyState interactive and webnavigation.onDomContentLoaded. Thank you!

Comment: @MTCoster That is consistent with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) documentation, i.e. that deferred scripts are guaranteed to have executed once the `DOMContentLoaded` event is dispatched. But I'm confused about how to square that with the claim [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#checking_whether_loading_is_already_complete) that you can infer that `DOMContentLoaded` has fired if `document.readyState` is not `loading` (what about `interactive`?)

Comment: A solution is also in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968300/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-document-readystate-is-complete/73750432#73750432

Answer (score 5):

As per accepted answer:

> The value of the `readyState` property is always `"interactive"` when `DOMContentLoaded` has fired.

## **Wrong**

It has either of:

- `interactive`
- `complete`

> **document . readyState**  [ref.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#reporting-document-loading-status)
>
> Returns `"loading"` while the Document is loading, `"interactive"` once it is finished parsing but still loading subresources, and `"complete"` once it has loaded.

If one attach an event listener to `readystatechange` ***before*** Document has state `interactive` one can check for `interactive` alone, like with example from MDN. Then one will catch the state if it ever reaches it.

However if one check the state at a later stage it is not.

Also by example from MDN, these are equal:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
    initApplication();
  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    initApplication();
});
```

That does not mean:

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading')
    assert(document.readyState === 'interactive')
```

Which the answer suggests.

As to say:

- `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`

will never equal to:

- `window.addEventListener('load', ...`

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `readyState` property is at least `"interactive"` when `DOMContentLoaded` is fired. As @MTCoster pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346746/document-readystate-on-domcontentloaded#comment87562914_13346803), the event is deferred until linked scripts with `defer` attribute and `module` scripts, linked or inline, have executed. See also [this post](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/).