# Values for document.readyState in Android 2.3 browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, android-browser

I found out that once the document has loaded, then in the Android 2.3.5 browser, the value of `document.readyState` is `"loaded"` instead of [the standard `"interactive"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#current-document-readiness).

Where are the possible values of `document.readyState` documented for the Android 2.3 browser?

Comment: Old question (but so is my phone) with no reply at all... from my tests I conclude that there is no `interactive` state only with Android 2. Also `onreadystatechange ` is not supported.