# DomContentLoaded event on image preview pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

For example I have some image src.

[image]

I open this page in the new chrome tab.
On the page I have script that runs on `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     console.log('done');/*call to init function*/
 }, false);
```

However in this case the event is never fire. On the regular page with full CSS and hierarchical DOM tree all works fine. Only in the case with open image alone in the new tab something goes wrong or I miss some details in using this event .
Will be glad of any help or explanation

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k1L6mwzs/)

***UPDATE***

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346746/document-readystate-on-domcontentloaded) , the DOMContentLoaded event fires only on `document.readyState=interactive`, but the image view page never gave this status... So my question is there is any workaround of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

all works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/k1L6mwzs/2/

in jsfiddle you had `onLoad` event setted in list at the left side of screen, and your `js` code is called after it.

But `DOMContentLoaded` event fires BEFORE `onload`, thats why you don't see your alert.

(if your problem is not in jsfiddle, please show us full code of page (html) and script. You are also use jQuery -> for what?)

Comment: try to open the image src page that I attached to the question, and run on console 'document.readyState'... it will show you 'complete' (it shown me this status). According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346746/document-readystate-on-domcontentloaded, the DOMContentLoaded event fires only on 'document.readyState=interactive', but the image view page never gave me this status... So my question is there is any workaround of this issue?

Comment: realy? by me all work fine, and `document.readystate` is `interactive`. http://jsfiddle.net/k1L6mwzs/2/  I don't know what you are trying to do, but all works correct.