# EventListener for state when all scripts have been executed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to auto-populate some input fields when the page **fully loads**. However, there are other scripts I can't control which change the page. So if I try to do anything like these options, I get element not found.

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    init();
});
```

or

```
if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
  init();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    init();
  });
}
```

When can I call `init()` so that all other scripts have been executed (aka I won't get element not found error)? Right now, I am using setTimeOut() which obviously isn't ideal.

References:

[How to detect if DOMContentLoaded was fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457891/how-to-detect-if-domcontentloaded-was-fired)

[document.readyState on DOMContentLoaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346746/document-readystate-on-domcontentloaded)

Comment: if it helps, you can inspect each change that happens to the document using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: There's no such event unless the site itself fires a custom nonstandard one, which you can try finding in devtools, but that's rare. The universal solution is MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
  if (document.querySelector("input[data-automation-id]")) {
    init();
    observer.disconnect();
  }
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Thought of this based on the comment. However, it is still a proxy so this does not guarantee ALL input fields are available.

Comment: You are using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) wrong and need to understand the documentation.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?